# What are the simplest set of steps I can use to build the Linux kernel with LTO and/or PGO?

Tags: kernel, compiling, compiler

I've been looking for a simple guide how to do this, and it's been around for so long that it seems to me like something should exist that explains how to build the Linux kernel in Ubuntu with LTO + PGO optimizations.